# Is there an online service for checking the health of online services?

Tags: healthcheck

I have a web service in Amazon WS on port 443. Is there an online service that can monitor my service and email me if, for example, https://myservice.org returns an error?

Comment: There are many, yes. https://ohdear.app/ https://www.pingdom.com/ etc.

Comment: Even Amazon can do that itself.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon cloud watch can be used monitor webservices.